# C++: callback class that contains object (Async Server / Clients)

Tags: c++, callback

I have a problem that is hard to describe, but I am sure there have been many solutions. Unfortunately, I can't find the **right** terms to search for.

I have two classes, Server and Client. The server class contains a vector that holds Client (connection). Server contains a write() method that iterates over the vector and calls write() on each Client. Each client calls async_write() (from boost).

I would like the Client to be able to callback directly into Server, so that if the async_write() fails, the Server object can remove the client that failed.

It must be do-able somehow, what I am missing please? I've tried passing down a function pointer to the a member function of the Server class to the write() in the client but that would not compile. Any suggestions please?

Comment: is it a tcp connection?

Comment: Yes it is, so I expect the async_write() to fail with boost::system::error_code being set. In that case, I want my Server object to remove it's Client object (which async_write() failed).

Comment: If client's async_write has failed to write to the server, chances are your callback to the server will also fail.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that my Server class holds a vector of Stream (each stream is a client connected). The server periodically sends data (via write()) on each Stream. If the async_write() fails in the Stream, I want the server to remove that Stream from it's vector of Stream.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways you could achieve removal of stale connection from the server side, as against the client side you are trying to achieve.

```
//Pseudo code only
for(i=0; i < vectorOfClientConnections.size(); ++i){
  errorCode = vectorOfClientConnections.write(buf);
  if (errorCode < 0) {
    if( errno == EPIPE ){ /* just an example */
      //Erase the connection from the vector
      //Do resource handling
    } 
    else if( errno == EAGAIN ){ /* or EWOULDBLOCK*/
      // OS buffer exhausted, handle the bytes written
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: vectorOfClientConnections.write(buf) would be asynchronous (write() calls async_write() which returns immediately). Are you saying I should check on the next write()? Not sure how the code would work otherwise as write() is non-blocking.

Comment: write api would fail if there's any error in the underlying tcp connection. Refer man page of write http://linux.die.net/man/2/write If you try to write on a stale tcp fd, write would fail, irrespective of its blocking/non-blocking nature.